# Как сделать бесконечный цикл который добавляет +1 монету за секунду?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я хочу сделать так чтобы при нажатие на кнопку запускался цикл который добавляет +1 монету за секунду.

```
var coins = 0;
var coin = $('#coins').val();

$("#click").click(function(){
        if(coin>="0" && click=="1"){
            coins++;
            $("#coins").val(coins);
        }else if(coin>="0" && click=="2"){
            coins++;
            coins++;
            $("#coins").val(coins);
        }else if(coin>="0" && click=="3"){
            coins++;
            coins++;
            coins++;
            $("#coins").val(coins);
        };
    });
```

Весь код:

```
$(function(){    //++++++++ +++++++++++++++++ toy TOY
    //------------------------ center -------------------------------------
    var click = 1;
    var coins = 0;
    var coin = $('#coins').val();
    
    $('input').attr('disabled','disabled');
    
    $("#click").click(function(){
        if(coin>="0" && click=="1"){
            coins++;
            $("#coins").val(coins);
        }else if(coin>="0" && click=="2"){
            coins++;
            coins++;
            $("#coins").val(coins);
        }else if(coin>="0" && click=="3"){
            coins++;
            coins++;
            coins++;
            $("#coins").val(coins);
        };
    });
    //------------------------ left div -----------------------------------
    //--------- LevelUp1 ---------
    var leve1 = 0;
    
    $("#up").click(function(){
        if(coins>="20" && leve1=="0"){
            var cikl1;
            for (cikl1 = 0; cikl1 < 20; cikl1++) {
                coins--;
                $("#coins").val(coins);
            };
            leve1++;
            
            $(".level1").val("1");
            $("#ClickMouse").val("2");
            $(".by1").val("50");
            click++;
        }else if(coins>="50" && leve1=="1"){
            var cikl2;
            for (cikl2 = 0; cikl2 < 50; cikl2++) {
                coins--;
                $("#coins").val(coins);
            };
            leve1++;
            
            $(".level1").val("2");
            $("#ClickMouse").val("3");
            $(".by1").val("100");
            click++;
        };
    });
    
    
    
    //------------------------ right div ----------------------------------
    
})    //++++++++++  +++++++++++++++ toy TOY
```

Comment: Используйте ```setInterval```, а так же почитайте про типы данных.. а то вы число со строкой сравниваете.

Comment: Есть еще прекрасный оператор ```+=```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let button = document.querySelector('#button');
let coins = 0;

button.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
  setInterval(() => {
    coins++;
    console.log(coins);
  }, 1000);
}, {
  once: true
});
```

```html
<button type="button" id="button">Start</button>
```

Comment: Я считаю это не корректно, таймер нужно очищать перед запуском иначе их наплодит.

Comment: @oliver-patterson , Добавил `once: true`, для одноразового запуска. Да и я не буду же super quality функцию писать, нужен был наверное только пример. Человеку вообще скорее всего она на jQuery нужна.